# creating a prestashop module trying to Show error on PrestaShop Module

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm trying to display an error when the user submits data from a form, but no error.

try putting in the driver (forcing you to show me an error)
as follows

```
   public function postProcess()
    {
    $ this-> errors [] = Tools :: DisplayError ('Invalid e-mail address');
    }
```

and in the template

```
{include file = "$ tpl_dir. / errors.tpl"}

<form method="post" action="{$request_uri|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="std" id="form_confirmPassword">
<fieldset>
<p class="text">
<label for="email"> {l s = 'E-mail'} </ label>
<input type = "text" id = "email" name = "email" value = "{if isset ($ smarty.post.email)} {$ smarty.post.email | escape: 'htmlall': 'UTF-8 '| stripslashes} {/ if} "/>
</ p>
</ fieldset>
</ form>
```

Anyway i can't get show any messsage error like prestashop native module display...

Comment: Are you sure that you assign your errors[] array with the smarty varible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing everything wrong.

was calling from a link to a page that was not either a class or a controller.

My last call was ...

```
{base_dir} {$ modules / mymodule / beginprofile.php
```

and on that page I had all the logic like a normal PHP page.

and change this.

```
{base_dir} {$ index.php? fc = module & MyModule = extrainfos & controller = beginprofile
```

I then moving all functions to a new class that extended the class FrontController inside MYMODULE's controller folder

and worked so doing more than that.